# Function take in array of string return only strings with that have number(s) in them. Or return empty array if none

Tags: javascript, arrays

The function has 1 parameter: an array. It should iterate through the array and return strings that contain a number in them. If none of them have an number it will return an empty array.

The code I have written so far seems too verbose. Sometimes it does not return the correct value. I am looking for any ways to shorten the code or improve it.

```
function numInStr(arr) {
    var stringsWithNum = [];
  for(var x = 0; x < arr.length - 1; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < arr[x].length - 1;y++) {
      //console.log(typeof arr[x][y]);
            if('0123456789'.indexOf(arr[x][y]) !== -1) {        
                stringsWithNum.push(arr[x]);
        break;              
      }
    }
  }
  return stringsWithNum;
}
```

Comment: Your loops have the wrong ending index. `x < arr.length - 1` should be `x < arr.length` and `y < arr[x].length - 1` should be `y < arr[x].length`. You can also use `arr.forEach()` instead of `for (...)` to avoid needlessly creating and maintaining the `x` array index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten your code considerably by using `.filter()` to filter out the elements containing numbers, and using `.match()` to test whether the elements contain a number.

This eliminates the need to create and maintain (and possibly incorrectly set) array indexes.

```js
function numInStr(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function (elmt) {
        return elmt.match(/\d/)
    })
}

console.log(numInStr(['foo', 'ab12', '34asdf', 'bar']))
// Array [ "ab12", "34asdf" ]
```